# Is $C^1$ Banach space with usual norm?

Tags: metric-spaces, banach-spaces, cauchy-sequences

[Prove that $C^1([a,b])$ with the $C^1$- norm is a Banach Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507263/prove-that-c1a-b-with-the-c1-norm-is-a-banach-space) . I know that $C^1([a,b])$ is a Banach space with the $C^1$ norm. But is it a Banach space with the usual norm $||f||_\infty=sup|f|$ ? I think it shouldn´t be, but when trying to prove it I always get that it is. Any idea of a Cauchy sequence in $C^1[0,1]$ which is not convergent  ?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2767254/prove-that-c10-1-cdot-is-not-a-banach-space).

Comment: the "usual norm" for $C^1$ is of course, the $C^1$ norm.

Comment: Approximate $\sqrt x$ on $[0,1]$ by  a sequence of polynomials.

Comment: Thank you David, I didn´t found that question.